# Calling an embedded XPCService from external App

Tags: macos

I have two independent applications (cocoa), one main, the other slave.

The main application application is embedding a XPCService, which is correctly launched when the application is opened. No problems so far for connecting and exchanging data with that service (I also see this XPCService in the Activity Monitor).

But I want the other slave application to connect and send data to that XPC Service (and then to the main first application) after it has been launched by the main one.
Using NSXPCConnection (with initWithMachServiceName), and the correct Service bundle identifier doesn't work: no NewConnection delegate is called so the slave application never reach the service.

What am I missing ? Is what I want is possible with NSXPCConnection ? 
Is it because I need the XPCService (within plist) to be shared in some way ? In that case what should I do ?

I can't find any information about this sort connection !
Thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 0):

> "I have two independent applications "

As stated in [Apple's Documentation for XPC](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingXPCServices.html):

> an XPC service is private, and is available only to the main application that contains it.

For security, an application that contains an XPC helper app gets signed to ensure that only the main application is allowed to call up on its helper.

However, it should be noted that the documentation also states

> A connection is a virtual endpoint; it is independent of whether an actual instance of the service binary is running. The service binary is launched on demand.
>
> A connection can also be sent as a piece of data in an XPC message. Thus, you can pass a connection through XPC to allow one service to communicate with another service (for example).

Though I've not seen this in practice, it does imply that you may be able to initiate the connection from the main application to the XPC helper and send this connection to your 'slave' app.

Comment: Thanks. I will check that. I fully understood now why an embedded service can't be reached directly from an external app. I will also try to create this service through an independant project (not embedded in the app) and will come back here for the result.